# IntelliJ and SVN - Automatically add to SVN files not added from IntelliJ

Tags: svn, version-control, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm working on an IntelliJ project managed by SVN repository. Everything is configured right and working.

When I create a new file in IntelliJ, the file appears automatically in green. That's ok, it means that the file has been marked for addition to SVN at the next commit. (I already have *Settings -> Version Control -> Add silently* ticked).

However, when I add a new file "manually" (IE: I navigate to the project directory and put some new files there) IntelliJ marks these files in red (which means: "I saw you've added some new files, but you still need to right-click on each of those file and choose *Subversion -> Add* to add them to SVN). Is there any way to make IntelliJ to add the files automatically ?

My problem is that sometimes I have to remember to add 20+ files planted in different folders of my project and there is no option to add all these recursively to SVN. The new files are add into the the project folder by an external software that does not support integration with svn.

Comment: I think this is a related request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73077. Your vote is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround for this:

All the files not added to SVN can be found by opening the *Changes* window (ALT + 9) and choosing the *Local* tab. Under *Default* there is an option called *Unversioned Files* and a link to browse these files. 
[image: screenshot]
There I can right click on the folder containing the items I want to add and these will be added recursively. That makes me save much time.